# How can I find how many conditions that I would expect from search box with filtering options

Tags: c#, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to implement a search box with a number of filtering option I would like to count how many possible conditions that I would have. for example I have two search boxes with options to search by title or search by location or search by both and also I have two options display results based on the last 24 hour posted results or within 3 days. Some of the conditions for instance could be that search location is empty where the rest is not and another example would be that the option 24 hours is on where the rest is not. the attempted solution for this is as below but what I am looking for is the accurate way of counting all of these conditions and how I can structure them within a simple code.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SearchResult(int? page, string searchTitle = "" , string searchLocation = "", string last24="", string last3Days= "")
    {      
        setUpApi(searchTitle, searchLocation);
        var result = new List<AllJobModel>();
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        var time = now.AddHours(-24).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").ToString();
        var time2 = now.AddHours(-48).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").ToString();
        var time3 = now.AddHours(-72).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").ToString();
        var timesNow = now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").ToString();
        if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTitle) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchLocation)) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(last24) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(last3Days)))
        {
            setUpApi(searchTitle, searchLocation);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(last24))
            {
                result = db.AllJobModel.Where(a => a.JobTitle.Contains(searchTitle) && a.locationName.Contains(searchLocation) && a.PostedDate == timesNow ||
                a.PostedDate.Equals(time)).ToList();
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(last3Days))
            {
                result = db.AllJobModel.Where(a => a.JobTitle.Contains(searchTitle) && a.locationName.Contains(searchLocation) && a.PostedDate == timesNow ||
               a.PostedDate.Equals(time3) || a.PostedDate == time2 || a.PostedDate == time).ToList();
            }
        }
        else if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTitle) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchLocation) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(last24) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(last3Days)))
        {
            result = db.AllJobModel.Where(a => a.JobTitle.Contains(searchTitle) && a.locationName.Contains(searchLocation)).ToList();
        }
        else if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTitle) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchLocation)) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(last24) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(last3Days)))
        {
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(last24))
            {
                result = db.AllJobModel.Where(a => a.PostedDate.Equals(time)).ToList();
            }else if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(last3Days))
            {
                result = db.AllJobModel.Where(a => a.PostedDate == timesNow ||
              a.PostedDate.Equals(time3) || a.PostedDate == time2 || a.PostedDate == time).ToList();
            }      
        }
        else
        {
            result = (from app in db.AllJobModel select app).ToList();
        }


        return View(result.ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 5));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the amount of permutations by multiplying the distinct options for each filter. In your case, this gives you `2 * 2 * 3 = 12` permutations (two options for the `searchTitle`, two for the `searchLocation`, three total for the time filters).

As for dealing with these permutations, if the effect of a filter should be the same regardless of the other active filters, you can take advantage of the fact that you can filter an enumerable object in multiple separate `Where` calls, each applying additional filtering to the result set.

Given my interpretation of the intention of your code, I came up with the following:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SearchResult(
    int? page,
    string searchTitle = "",
    string searchLocation = "",
    string last24 = "",
    string last3Days = "")
{
    setUpApi(searchTitle, searchLocation);

    var result = db.AllJobModel;

    // Search filters
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTitle))
    {
        result = result.Where(a => a.JobTitle.Contains(searchTitle));
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchLocation))
    {
        result = result.Where(a => a.locationName.Contains(searchLocation));
    }

    // Time filters
    var hasTimeFilter = !(string.IsNullOrEmpty(last24) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(last3Days));
    if (hasTimeFilter)
    {
        var numberOfAdditionalDays = string.IsNullOrEmpty(last24) ? 3 : 1;
        var totalValidDays = 1 + numberOfAdditionalDays;

        var now = DateTime.Now;
        var validDays = Enumerable.Range(0, totalValidDays).
            Select(i => now.AddDays(-1 * i).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")).
            ToList();

        result = result.Where(a => validDays.Contains(a.PostedDate));
    }

    return View(result.ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 5));
}
```

The above may not be precisely what you need, as I changed some of the boolean logic to what I *think* you were trying to do, and omitted a duplicate call to `setUpApi(searchTitle, searchLocation)`, but it should easy enough to modify to suit your requirements.